# What is the simplest way to set up "reply to this email directly"?

Tags: html, email, postfix-mta

I have a site that people communicate via private message.
I send npemail notifications to these people.

In the email notifications, I want the user to be able to hit reply on the email.  My system would then analyze the subject line and write the message to the database for that user.

I have an email server set up (followed instructions to install dovecot and postfix).  However, its a very basic set up and I'm completely clueless how to implement the system I just described.

I'm looking for a good overview answer or a link to a tutorial that goes through this.

Comment: I basically want my mail server to detect incoming mails and then act accordingly...

Comment: One such way is to connect to the imap server and idle. In Ruby, use `Net::IMAP` and `add_response_handler`. There are various ways to do this. There are votes to close this question. Pick a specific goal and try something, edit your question, then flag it for re-opening.

Comment: @joeframbach IMO, the question is clear enough as it is. He specified that his mailserver is postfix and implied that he has full control over it, meaning that it's simple to use a `.forward` file or so to achieve his goal.

Answer (score 0):

There's a trick you can make use of: Mails to `user+extension@domain` go to the same mailbox as mails to `user@domain`. I'd use that instead of the subject line to find out which message the reply is about – this lets the user choose a custom subject line.

To let mails to a certain user go directly into a program, the probably easiest way is to put a `.forward` file into his home directory. Into that file, write `| <path to executable>`. The full mail (including headers) will be handed to the specified executable via stdin and a few environment variables with metadata (e.g. `EXTENSION`) will be set.

You might want to do [`man 8 local`](http://www.postfix.org/local.8.html).